# How cheaply can we eat in Ireland while still experiencing traditional Irish foods?

Tags: food-and-drink, ireland

Two of us will be visiting Dublin, Galway, Killarney, and Kilkenny for about 3 days each and will need lunch and dinner every day. We are on a budget and won't be eating at any 5* restaurants, but we don't want to miss out on the foods that the Irish traditionally eat.

Comment: You forgot the breakfast! The Irish mostly eat a snack (a sandwich or fried snacks) for lunch (but they have very good sandwiches!). For diner I don't know, it seems most restaurants are either fast food or ‘exotic’ (Italian, French…)

Comment: @Relaxed I didn't include breakfast because some of them are included with the hotel and we will likely purchase a hotel breakfast at those it is not included with the price. Unless there's a reason we should skip hotel breakfast and eat somewhere else?

Comment: No particular reason, it's just that the breakfast is an important meal there. Beyond that, I have actually never stayed at hotels in Ireland, they always seemed very expensive compared to B&Bs.

Comment: modern irish food is mcdonalds.

Comment: or [Supermacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermac%27s) - I recall it being like a mix of McDs and KFC!

Comment: Pretty cheaply - http://www.tesco.ie/groceries/product/browse/default.aspx?N=4294953979.

Answer (score 9):

Easily enough if you go to local pubs, and stay in B&Bs. Every town will usually have them, and often with live music in the pubs at night.  They're usually friendly, fun, and serve good food.

Source: have been to Ireland twice, first time spent a week travelling around and eating only in pubs, and the occasional bed & breakfast or hostel that served food.

Food included full Irish breakfasts, Irish stew, black pudding, coddle, and so much more, for a list to get your tastebuds watering, have a look [at the Wiki page for Irish dishes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Irish_dishes).

EDIT: realised you also asked the rough price. I went a few years back, but a similar [thread on Thorntree says around 10 Euro per meal](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g186605-i90-k6005983-Ireland_Pub_Suggestions_Average_Meal_Price-Dublin_County_Dublin.html) which sounds fair from my memories.

Answer (score 2):

Many hotels or B&Bs will serve breakfasts (mostly with a choice of either a traditional Irish fried breakfast, or cereal/pastries). Probably just as good as going elsewhere. Sometimes hotel breakfasts can be expensive for what you get, but unless you know a local cafe selling breakfast, a hotel breakfast is probably your best bet.